# Проблема с получением данных из БД и с сохранением объектов в БД Oracle

Tags: java, spring, oracle, hibernate, jackson

Мне надо получить список объектов `file` из базы данных через `GET` запрос.
Есть два класса:

**`File:`**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "FILE_")
public class File {

    private Long id;
    private Long storageId;
    private String name;
    private String format;
    private Long size;
    private Storage storage;

    public File() {
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "F_SQ", sequenceName = "FILE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "F_SQ")
    @Column(name = "FILE_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    //@JoinColumn(name = "STORAGE_ID_F")
    public Long getStorageId() {
        return storageId;
    }

    @Column(name = "NAME_FILE")
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Column(name = "FORMAT_FILE")
    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    @Column(name = "SIZE_FILE")
    public Long getSize() {
        return size;
    }

    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Storage.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "STORAGE_ID_F")
    public Storage getStorage() {
        return storage;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static File createFromJson(String jsonString){

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        File file = null;
        try {
            file = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, File.class);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return file;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setStorageId(Long storageId) {
        this.storageId = storageId;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public void setSize(Long size) {
        this.size = size;
    }

    public void setStorage(Storage storage) {
        this.storage = storage;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        File file = (File) o;
        return Objects.equals(storageId, file.storageId) &&
                Objects.equals(name, file.name) &&
                Objects.equals(format, file.format) &&
                Objects.equals(size, file.size) &&
                Objects.equals(storage, file.storage);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(storageId, name, format, size, storage);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "File{" +
                "id=" + id +
                " name='" + name + '\'' +
                ", format='" + format + '\'' +
                ", size=" + size +
                ", storage=" + storage.getId() +
                '}';
    }
}
```

**`Storage`:**

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonCreator;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "STORAGE_")
public class Storage {

    private Long id;
    private String formatsSupported;
    private String storageCountry;
    private Long storageSize;
    private List<File> files;

    public Storage() {
    }

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "ST_SQ", sequenceName = "STORAGE_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "ST_SQ")
    @Column(name = "STORAGE_ID")
    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Column(name = "FORMAT_SUPPORTED")
    public String getFormatsSupported() {
        return formatsSupported;
    }

    @Column(name = "COUNTRY_STORAGE")
    public String getStorageCountry() {
        return storageCountry;
    }

    @Column(name = "SIZE_STORAGE")
    public Long getStorageSize() {
        return storageSize;
    }

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "storage", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, targetEntity = File.class)
    public List<File> getFiles() {
        return files;
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public static Storage createFromJson(String jsonString){

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        Storage storage = null;
        try {
            storage = objectMapper.readValue(jsonString, Storage.class);
        }catch (IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return storage;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setFormatsSupported(String formatsSupported) {
        this.formatsSupported = formatsSupported;
    }

    public void setStorageCountry(String storageCountry) {
        this.storageCountry = storageCountry;
    }

    public void setStorageSize(Long storageSize) {
        this.storageSize = storageSize;
    }

    public void setFiles(List<File> files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
}
```

В классе `Controller` метод с запросом на получение списка объектов из базы данных, использую БД `Oracle`:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import dz_spring_3.dao.FileDAO;
import dz_spring_3.dao.StorageDAO;
import dz_spring_3.model.File;
import dz_spring_3.model.Storage;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;

@org.springframework.stereotype.Controller
public class Controller {

    @Autowired
    Service service;

    @Autowired
    StorageDAO storageDAO;

    @Autowired
    FileDAO fileDAO;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/saveFile", produces = "text/plain")
    @ResponseBody
    public String saveFile(HttpServletRequest req)throws IOException {

        File file = mappingFile(req);

        if (file.getId() != null)
            return "Storage with id - " + file.getId() + " can`t be saved in DB.";

        file.setStorageId(storageDAO.findById(3L).getId());

        service.saveFile(file);

        return "File with id - " + file.getId() + " saved success.";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/file", produces = "text/plain")
    @ResponseBody
    public String getAllFile(){

        return service.getAllFile().toString();
    }

    private File mappingFile(HttpServletRequest req)throws IOException {

        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        try(BufferedReader reader = req.getReader()) {
            String line;

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                System.out.println("Line in wile (mapping) - " + line);
                stringBuilder.append(line);
            }
        }

        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

        String input = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(stringBuilder.toString());

        File file = objectMapper.convertValue(input, File.class);

        return file;
    }
```

**Класс `FileDAO`:**

```
import dz_spring_3.model.File;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.query.NativeQuery;

import javax.persistence.TypedQuery;
import java.util.List;

public class FileDAO extends GeneralDAO<File> {

    private static final String SQL_GET_ALL_FILES = "SELECT * FROM FILE_";
    private static final String SQL_GET_BY_ID_FILE = "SELECT * FROM FILE_ WHERE FILE_ID = ?";

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<File> getAllFile(){
        List<File> files;

        try(Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession()) {

            NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery(SQL_GET_ALL_FILES);
            files = query.addEntity(File.class).list();

        }catch (HibernateException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new HibernateException("Operation failed");
        }
        return files;
    }

    public File saveFile(File file) {

        Transaction tr = null;
        try(Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            tr = session.getTransaction();
            tr.begin();

            session.save(file);

            tr.commit();
        }catch (HibernateException e){
            System.err.println("Save is failed.");
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            if (tr != null)
                tr.rollback();
        }

        return file;
    }

    public void updateFile(File file){

        Transaction transaction = null;
        try(Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();

            session.update(file);

            transaction.commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e){

            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.rollback();

            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new HibernateException("Operation failed.");
        }
    }

    public void deleteFile(Long id){

        Transaction transaction = null;
        try(Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession()) {
            transaction = session.getTransaction();
            transaction.begin();

            session.delete(findById(id));

            transaction.commit();
        }
        catch (HibernateException e){

            if (transaction != null)
                transaction.rollback();

            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new HibernateException("Operation failed.");
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public File findById(Long id){

        File file;

        try(Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession()) {

            NativeQuery query = session.createNativeQuery(SQL_GET_BY_ID_FILE);
            if (getSingleResult(query, id) == null){
                file = null;
            }
            else
                file = (File) query.addEntity(File.class).setParameter(1, id).getSingleResult();

        }catch (HibernateException e){
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
            throw new HibernateException("Operation failed.");
        }
        return file;
    }

    private <T> T getSingleResult(TypedQuery<T> query, Long id){
        query.setMaxResults(1);

        List<T> list = query.setParameter(1, id).getResultList();

        if (list == null || list.isEmpty()){

            return null;
        }
        return list.get(0);
    }
}
```

После того, как запускаю сервер `Tomcat`и делаю запрос 
`http://localhost:8080/file`падает несколько ошибок, вот стектрэйс:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    Root Cause

    javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
        org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
        org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423)
        dz_spring_3.dao.FileDAO.getAllFile(FileDAO.java:24)
        dz_spring_3.Service.getAllFile(Service.java:56)
        dz_spring_3.Controller.getAllFile(Controller.java:111)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    Root Cause

    org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not execute query
        org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:47)
        org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2695)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
        org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2161)
        org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016)
        org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152)
        org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
        dz_spring_3.dao.FileDAO.getAllFile(FileDAO.java:24)
        dz_spring_3.Service.getAllFile(Service.java:56)
        dz_spring_3.Controller.getAllFile(Controller.java:111)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    Root Cause

    java.sql.SQLException: Недопустимое имя столбца
        oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.getColumnIndex(OracleStatement.java:3965)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.findColumn(InsensitiveScrollableResultSet.java:299)
        oracle.jdbc.driver.GeneratedResultSet.getLong(GeneratedResultSet.java:1361)
        org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$2.doExtract(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:63)
        org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicExtractor.extract(BasicExtractor.java:47)
        org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:261)
        org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:257)
        org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeGet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:247)
        org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.hydrate(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:333)
        org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.hydrate(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2854)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.loadFromResultSet(Loader.java:1747)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.instanceNotYetLoaded(Loader.java:1673)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRow(Loader.java:1562)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:732)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.processResultSet(Loader.java:991)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:949)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:341)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2692)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2675)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2507)
        org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2502)
        org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:335)
        org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2161)
        org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016)
        org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152)
        org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
        dz_spring_3.dao.FileDAO.getAllFile(FileDAO.java:24)
        dz_spring_3.Service.getAllFile(Service.java:56)
        dz_spring_3.Controller.getAllFile(Controller.java:111)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:634)
        org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
        org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
    Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server logs.
```

Я так понимаю, эта проблема идёт из-за поля `storageId`, когда его убираю совсем, то данные из базы считываются. Но это поле мне надо для того, чтобы сохраняемому в базу объекту `file` просетить `id` хранилища `storage` в котором находится этот файл. Ну и при попытке сохранить `file` в базу через `Post` запрос, тоже падает ошибка:

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to release JDBC Connection
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to release JDBC Connection
org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:149)
    org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:157)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1423)
    org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
    dz_spring_3.dao.StorageDAO.getSingleResult(StorageDAO.java:119)
    dz_spring_3.dao.StorageDAO.findById(StorageDAO.java:103)
    dz_spring_3.Controller.saveFile(Controller.java:98)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to release JDBC Connection
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)
    org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:111)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:97)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.releaseConnection(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:199)
    org.hibernate.resource.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.afterTransaction(LogicalConnectionManagedImpl.java:162)
    org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.afterTransaction(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:288)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterOperation(SessionImpl.java:557)
    org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:2168)
    org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.list(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:1016)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.NativeQueryImpl.doList(NativeQueryImpl.java:152)
    org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1414)
    org.hibernate.query.Query.getResultList(Query.java:146)
    dz_spring_3.dao.StorageDAO.getSingleResult(StorageDAO.java:119)
    dz_spring_3.dao.StorageDAO.findById(StorageDAO.java:103)
    dz_spring_3.Controller.saveFile(Controller.java:98)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:175)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:446)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:434)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:938)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:870)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)
    org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:863)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:660)
org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:741)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
</pre><p><b>Root Cause</b></p><pre>java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Закрытое соединение
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Файл `hibernate.cfg.xml`:**

[image: hibernate.cfg.xml]

[image: <code>Postman</code>]

Что-то делаю не правильно, а вот что именно не могу понять.
Прошу подсказать или объяснить, как мне получить список объектов и сохранять объекты `file` в базу данных.

Comment: В каком месте у вас зкрывается соединение?

Comment: Roman C, тут не влезло всё описание, слишком объёмно я вопрос описал, добавляю скрин с недостающим описанием ошибки

Comment: Можете сбросить конфигурацию Hibernate?

Comment: Roman C, добавил `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: Вы не указали диалект для работы с базой данных.

Comment: Roman C, вроде бы я его указывал в самой Intelij IDEA при подключении БД... попробую добавить в файл конфига

Comment: Roman C, не помогло, добавил в конфиг строку `<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>` , выполняю `Post` запрос на сохранение файла, но падает ошибка `Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException</p><p><b>Description</b> The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.</p><p><b>Exception</b></p><pre>org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: Это уже другая ошибка. К тому же не видно полный стэк и невозможно определить главную причину. Если причина та же самая, что и была, то она должна воспроизводиться.

Comment: Roman C, я добавил скриншот из `Postman` с описанием ошибки. Не могу понять почему не маппится объект `file`

Comment: Это очень сложно понять но в методе `File.toString()` возникает ошибка, потому что поле `storage` не инициализировано.

Comment: Roman C, да, я это вижу... а как мне это исправить не пойму ((

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы исправить `NullPointerException` в методе `File.toString()` нужно переписать метод

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "File{" +
            "id=" + id +
            " name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", format='" + format + '\'' +
            ", size=" + size +
            ", storage=" + (storage != null?storage.getId():"null") +
            "}";
}
```

---

Потом вы перепутали сериализацию с десериализацией, нужно писать что-то типа

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

String input = stringBuilder.toString();

File file = objectMapper.readValue(input, File.class);
```

но `storage` у вас неверно задан, т.е. вы можете использовать

```
String input in (mapping) - "{\t\"name\":\"File02\",\t\"format\":\"doc\",\t\"size\":\"200\",\t\"storage\":{\"id\":\"3\"}}"
```

---

Потом у вас проблема с соединениями, что соединения не закрываются как следует, и с каждым запросом создается новое количество соединений. Некоторые соединения продолжают использоваться после того как они были закрыты. Для того, чтобы исправить эту ошибку нужно закрывать фактор сессий (если вы его постоянно создаете, правда непонятно зачем, но это уже ваше дело). Например можно использовать

```
try(SessionFactory factory = createSessionFactory();Session session = factory.openSession()) {
```

Comment: Roman C, спасибо, с Вашей помощью понял где были ошибки и что я не правильно делал ... я сессии закрываю в трае с ресурсами `try(Session session = createSessionFactory().openSession())` , а ещё надо закрывать и `factory` ? `Factory` у меня в `GeneralDAO` находится и получаю к ней доступ через гетер и потом уже открываю сессию или так не совсем правильно ?

Comment: если у вас создается несколько екземпляров фактора сессии, то каждый экземпляр надо закрывать, если  он больше не нужен. Правильно было бы сделать его синглтоном и инектить в GeneralDAO, тогда из него уже можно получить сессию.

Comment: Roman C, у меня так и сделано, в `GeneralDAO` синглтон `SessionFactory`, создано поле `SessionFactory sessionFactory;` и в `FileDAO` я уже через геттер достаю это поле и создаю сессию в `try` с реусрсами, чтобы поток закрывался автоматически ... так правильно ?

Comment: Да, но у вас написано `createSessionFactory()`, и я подумал что вы создаете фактор сесий каждый раз при запросе, в связи с чем возникает ошибка `java.sql.SQLRecoverableException: Закрытое соединение`.

Answer (score 0):

> Но это поле мне надо для того, чтобы сохраняемому в базу объекту file
>   просетить id хранилища storage в котором находится этот файл

Внешний ключ для `storage` как самостоятельная сущность в `File` не нужен; в коде эта связь выражается через `JoinColumn("STORAGE_ID_F")`:

```
@JsonIgnore
@ManyToOne(targetEntity = Storage.class, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "STORAGE_ID_F")
public Storage getStorage() {
    return storage;
}
```

Поле в БД добавится на основе данной конфигурации. Соответственно, в `PUT` необходимо в `File` добавлять экземпляр `Storage` через `setStorage()`, а не его идентификатор через `setStorageId()`.

Comment: tequillaz, не сохраняется `file` в базу, делаю файлу `setStorage(storage)` и падает ошибка `NPE`... я смотрю, что на этом этапе `File file = objectMapper.convertValue(input, File.class);` не маппится `file` из `json` строки, программа не выходит из метода  `mappingFile(HttpServletRequest req)` в классе `Contrjller`

Comment: tequillaz, верней хоть делаю сет, хоть не делаю, до этого места, где производится сет айдишника хранилища файлу, программа не доходит... как написал выше ошибка происходит где-то в маппинге файла из `json` строки

Comment: Покажите как тестовый запрос вызываете

Comment: tequillaz, использую `Postman` и в нём `Post` делаю запрос на сохранение файла `{
 "name":"File02",
 "format":"doc",
 "size":"200",
 "storage":"3"
}`

Comment: NPE у вас потому, что не десериализовалось сообщение на входе. Проверяйте что приходит (и приходит ли вообще) на вход. Конкретно в данном примере, подозреваю, что как минимум полю "storage" не может быть присвоено значение "3".